# How to set Text widget insert cursor by event.x_root and event.y_root in Tkinter/TkinterDnD

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to implement a Text Drag-n-Drop feature in my text editor. So far I get the text that I've dropped by `event.data`, and the position where I dropped the text by `event.x_root` and `event.y_root`. Please help me out with setting insert cursor of tk.Text by dropped position.

I'm using [tkdnd2.8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdnd/) as an extension and [TkinterDnD2](http://tkinterdnd.sourceforge.net) as a wrapper.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import TkinterDnD2.TkinterDnD as tkdnd


def drop(event):
    print("x: %d"%event.x_root, "y: %d"%event.y_root, "text:'%s'"%event.data)


root = tkdnd.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=10)
text.pack()
text.drop_target_register("DND_Text")
text.dnd_bind('<<Drop:DND_Text>>', drop)
root.mainloop()
```

If I drag a piece of text "SomeText" onto my text widget, here is the console output:

```
x: 60 y: 306 text:'SomeText'
```

Now I'm struggle on how to convert the position from pixel scale to character scale so that I can set it to text widget's INSERT cursor and insert text into my text widget.

Or, can I just emit a `"<Button-1>"` and `"<ButtonRelease-1>"` event at certain position? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: You should be able to use `"@60,306"` as the first parameter to `.insert()` to directly place the text at the drop location.

Comment: @jasonharper Hi, what does `"@60,306"` mean? I didn't get any result of this string on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an index by a coordinate using the format `@x,y`. From the canonical [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M7)

> **@x,y**
> Indicates the character that covers the pixel whose x and y coordinates within the text's window are x and y.

You should use the event x and y for the widget, not for the root. This is a standard, documented feature of the `Text` widget. You can use an f-string to create the index like so:

```
index = f"@{event.x},{event.y}"
```

The above will yield something like "@100,200".

You can use that index in any method call that takes an index. To convert that to a numerical index you can pass it to the `index` method. For example:

```
numerical_index = text.index(index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But for `event.x` and `event.y` it throws an exception: `AttributeError: 'DnDEvent' object has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: @EricKwok: ah, I didn’t realize that. I guess you’ll have to consult the documentation to see what attributes it has. It seems to not be consistent with other events. Regardless, the solution is to use the `@x,y` format for the index

Comment: Thanks again for the `@x,y` solution. I'm going to figure out how to calculate precise coordinate by `x_root` and `y_root` :)